# how to sort list in array and display in sort into textboxes

Tags: javascript, php

This is the index.php

This Javascript is for random numbers and displays into 9 text boxes.

```
  <script>
        function GetRandom()
        {
            var myElement = document.getElementById("no1")
            myElement.value = Math.floor((Math.random() * 1000) + 1);
            var myElement = document.getElementById("no2")
            myElement.value = Math.floor((Math.random() * 100) + 1);
            var myElement = document.getElementById("no3")
            myElement.value = Math.floor((Math.random() * 10000) + 1);
            var myElement = document.getElementById("no4")
            myElement.value = Math.floor((Math.random() * 1000) + 1);
            var myElement = document.getElementById("no5")
            myElement.value = Math.floor((Math.random() * 10000) + 1);
            var myElement = document.getElementById("no6")
            myElement.value = Math.floor((Math.random() * 1000) + 1);
            var myElement = document.getElementById("no7")
            myElement.value = Math.floor((Math.random() * 1000) + 1);
            var myElement = document.getElementById("no8")
            myElement.value = Math.floor((Math.random() * 1000) + 1);
            var myElement = document.getElementById("no9")
            myElement.value = Math.floor((Math.random() * 10000) + 1);
        }
    </script>
```

This javascript is take 9 text boxes value into array and sort list

```
    <script>
        function sortlist()
        {
            var captureNumb = document.getElementById("no1");
            var captureNumb = document.getElementById("no2");
            var captureNumb = document.getElementById("no3");
            var captureNumb = document.getElementById("no4");
            var captureNumb = document.getElementById("no5");
            var captureNumb = document.getElementById("no6");
            var captureNumb = document.getElementById("no7");
            var captureNumb = document.getElementById("no8");
            var captureNumb = document.getElementById("no9");
            var captureNumb = document.getElementById("no1");

            var numbers = captureNumb.value.split(" ");
            captureNumb.value = numbers.sort(function (a, b) {
                return a - b
            }).join(" ");
        }
    </script>

</head>
<body>
    <div class="form-inline">
        <div class="col-xs-12">
            <div class="form-group">

                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="no1" name="no1" placeholder="No 1">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="exampleInputName2"></label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="no2" name="no2" placeholder="No 2">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="exampleInputName2"></label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="no3" name="no3" placeholder="No 3">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="exampleInputName2"></label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="no4" name="no4" placeholder="No 4">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="exampleInputName2"></label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="no5" name="no5" placeholder="No 5">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="exampleInputName2"></label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="no6" name="no6" placeholder="No 6">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="exampleInputName2"></label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="no7" name="no7" placeholder="No 7">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="exampleInputName2"></label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="no8" name="no8" placeholder="No 8">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="exampleInputName2"></label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="no9" name="no9" placeholder="No 9">
            </div>
            <br><br><br> 
            <div align="center">



                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="GetRandom()">Populate</button>

                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="sortlist()" >Sort list</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Primary</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

1. How to click button sortlist and re-display follow by sort list?
2. tried to capture the value from 9 textboxes.

Comment: Don't ask unrelated questions in a single question.  [edit] your question to focus on one aspect here, and ask the other as a separate question.

Comment: you are assigning `document.getElementById("no1"),document.getElementById("no2"),...,document.getElementById("no9")` to same `var captureNumb`

Answer (score 0):

Your code need to be seriously looked at. You've got many repeated statements that could be solved with loops, and on every line where you redefine a variable, something like `var myElement = ...` two lines in a row, there is really no point in assigning it to a variable, as you never reference `myElement` and it's value is overridden on the next line.

In terms of what you're requesting regarding sorting, you need to dynamically insert them from some data structure.

```
<?php
    $values = someGeneratingFunction();
    $values = someSortFunction($values);
    for($i=0;$i<count($values);$i++) {
        echo "<input type=\"text\" class=\"form-control\" id=\"no" . $i . "\" name=\"no" . $i . "\" placeholder=\"No 1\">"
    }
    // Note the insertion of the ID values ("no1", "no2" etc.) using the loop instead of repeatedly typing the same thing.
?>
```

Keep in mind the above code doesn't use the entire HTML structure you've supplied, but you can use this as a general idea for how to achieve what you want. When you call a sort method, you can just re-run this code and it will just print all the elements in the array `values` in whatever order they've been put in.

**EDIT**

Consider the below JavaScript.

```
function sortList() {
    var values = [];
    for(i=1;i<10;i++) {
        values.push(document.getElementById("no".concat(i)));
    }
    return values.sort( function(a,b) { return a-b } );
}
```

We initialize an array to hold all the elements identified by the IDs `"no1"`, `"no2"` etc. Then we push them on, 1 by 1, in a for loop that accesses them all uses the indices (note this is what I was getting at, as this is better than repeating the same code 10 lines in a row, only altering a number.), and then we return our sorted array. Notice that we are passing a function as a parameter to when we call `values.sort( function(a,b) { return a-b } )`. This is because by default, the `.sort()` method sorts as strings, alphanumerically in ascending order. So the array `[1, 3, 200, 15000]` would be sorted as `[1, 15000, 200, 3]` which is quite clearly not in numeric order. By providing the additional function as a parameter, we tell it to subtract the two (it acts as our comparator) and then will provide us with accurate numeric results.

Comment: hello @James, i not very understanding. which means I dont need to user javascript?

Comment: You are able to do what you want using JavaScript or PHP I'm sure, I just wrote my answer in PHP as I'm more familiar and the logic of the solution remains the same.

Comment: I don't understand what you're trying to get at.

Comment: first I click the populate button, the 9 textboxes will generate the value,
second I click the sortlist button, the 9 textboxes will re-capture the value and follow by Ascending.